# Using 'FLT_EPSILON' for 64-bit iPhone 5S

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, 64-bit, ios7

I am getting the following error when trying to build my project using XCode 5.

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'FLT_EPSILON'
```

I have checked, and FLT_EPSILON (it shows up brown in Xcode), is defined in the "float.h" file.

What am I doing wrong?

---

This is the code where FLT_EPSILON is used:

```
if (someTimeInterval < 0.03 - FLT_EPSILON) {
    someTimeInterval = 0.1;
}
```

---

I figured out that this was occurring because I was trying to test it out on the iPhone 5S simulator (64 BIT).

I don't understand too well the differences when using the 64 bit simulator.
What should I include instead of FLT_EPSILON - and why doesn't it work with 64 bits?

Comment: Are you including "float.h"?

Comment: To clarify,"float.h" is part of the iOS SDK, so I assume I don't need to include it. And this was working properly on Xcode 4.

Comment: "I don't understand too well the differences when using the 64 bit simulator. What should I include instead of FLT_EPSILON - and why doesn't it work with 64 bits?" -> Anyone figured this out yet?

Comment: ^@Wirsing I found a solution, it's kind of weird how this issue is just for 64-bit devices though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why this did not work just for 64-bit devices.

But here's the solution:

> Make sure MobileCoreServices.framework is installed, and then it should work fine
>
> Import `<MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>`

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to disable modules in your project. To do this, go to build settings and set "Enable Modules" to "No".

That's a `clang` bug. Modules (`-fmodules` flag) are still experimental feature and when you mix Objective-C and C/C++ modules there can be some bugs.

See my demo project at github: [TestEpsilon](https://github.com/silvansky/TestEpsilon)

First target use modules, the second one no. To ensure we got "clean" build I added `DerivedData` and `ModulesCache` cleanup in pre-build scripts.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
#ifndef FLT_EPSILON
    #define FLT_EPSILON __FLT_EPSILON__
#endif
```

(this is how it's defined in `float.h`)